# Can i call a static java method using structural typing?

Tags: scala

I want to do something along the lines of (note that i know that this does not work, but my question is whether it is possible make it work):

```
object O {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val clazzname = classOf[System].getName
    val c = Class.forName(clazzname).asInstanceOf[{def currentTimeMillis: Long}]
    c.currentTimeMillis
  }
}
```

Is this possible? (without using reflection)

The real use case is for reading up serialized protobuf messages.

Comment: Got an answer on the scala-users mailinglist: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Structural-types-and-static-java-methods-td3026795.html#a3026795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No

I wish there were a better answer, but as you can already see from the mailing list, this isn't (currently) possible.  Hopefully the situation will improve as native reflection support in Scala matures.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
val c = new {                     
  def cm = System.currentTimeMillis  
}
```

However note, structural types use reflection internally.

Comment: No, it wouldnt, i get the name of the class as a string, then i need to call the currentTimeMillis method (or parseFrom in the GPB example) on the class loaded using Class.forName